# AngularJS init model from controls value

Tags: angularjs

I have very big form (~500 controls) and want to integrate AngularJS on it. I have one problem, when I'm setting `ng-model` property it resets my `value` property.

Is there any way to automatically set model values from input values properties (textareas and selects), without messing with controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "ng-init"

```
<input ng-model="data.instructions" ng-init="data.instructions='bla bla'">
```

But still, the recommended way is using a controller.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it doesn't work for `this.value` e.g. `ng-init="model_name=this.value"`

Comment: From where the initial value comes from? server side injection? or jquery/js element setter?

Comment: From server side. I have really complicated form and trying to find easy way to integrate angualar without changing form logic.

Comment: So inject it to the part in the example where I've put "bla bla" instead of the value...

Comment: It's hard to implement in my code. I'm looking rather to some configuration variable. Your way is ok but for me it'll be easier to do it controller. But thanks for response I didn't know about ng-init